# MacBook Pro (late 2008) new thermal paste applied, now how do I re-attach the cable for the cpu fans?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I'm working on a friend's MacbookPro5,1 15" from late 2008, which was overheating, so I knew from past experience, the thermal paste needed to be removed, and reappplied.  This was all achieved succcessfully.  The laptop powers on, boots up, and is running well.

The issue is, the cable for the 2 fans (1 for cpu, 1 for gpu) have been re-attached via electrical tape.  I wonder how long this will last, thought.

I have purchased Artic Silver's Thermal Adhesive, is this the preferred solution, for permanently re-attaching the cable for the fans, to the motherboard?

Any insights you have are greatly appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Both fans use Phillips head screws to attach themselves to the logic board.
[image]

Comment: Hi RedEagle2000,

Comment: Hi RedEagle2000, thank you for responding to my Question.  Sorry for not making this clear --  I still have the Phillips screws, and they are screwed in properly.  The issue I'm having, located In the picture you provided, is around 5:30ish --  between the red & white screws, middle - bottom of the picture.  The cpu fan's power connection to the motherboard has become loose, but all 4 capacitors are still intact, so I have taped these together via electrical tape ...  So, I should go with Epoxy, and not thermal adhesive?

Answer (score 1):

Jesuschrist Ryan, electrical tape? This means you stripped or lost your phillips screws?

Ok, first of all pray to the hardware gods that your thermal paste was applied correctly (you may want to check your temps with iStats or any other App of your choice).

If you're determined to leave those fans sealed for better or worse, use epoxy. Trust me, any tape will detach and your fans will become a drone in your Mac.
Bear in mind that thermal paste needs an average of 200 hours use to set. Good luck and may Steve Jobs forgive your unorthodoxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tape (that's some hot McGyver action!), I assume you lost or damaged those finicky little Phillips screws. Don't hack it together unless you expect this to be the end of life for this machine.

iFixIt (and probably a few other vendors) have [**replacement screw sets**](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Screw-Set/IF185-027-1). I'm not sure if the fan screws specifically are in there, but it's worth a shot. If you (or your friend) intend to perform any future maintenance on this machine, it's good piece of mind to have those in your kit.